# android: get the child of child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the "status" of the ride that is presently in my "History" node but first I had to get the "rideKey".

Global variables: String rideKey, String key.

**History node:**

```js
{
  "History" : {
    "-LGXaukR30LTjrL3ZNpt" : {
      "driver" : "ptnVOKounjXE9VrmZCCvKoZWluf1",
      "rating" : 0,
      "ridePrice" : 5.25,
      "rider" : "C0RjB5NPZcTvWz9XiUAhpTDOK0C2",
      "status" : "accepted",
      "timestamp" : 1530662726
    }
  }
}
```

**To get the rideKey, I did this:**

```
    DatabaseReference keyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History");
    keyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            rideKey = String.valueOf(mDatabase.child("History").push().getKey());
            Log.d(TAG, "getKey: key = " + rideKey);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

**This gives me all the keys in History, how can I get the most recent?**

Now, I, also need to get the "status" of the request.

But, when I try to get the status, it keeps coming up null.
I have tried putting another ValueEventListener inside the rideKey value event but still null

**Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?**
Much appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
Log.e(TAG, "I made it to getKeyAndStatus");

    DatabaseReference keyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History");
    keyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
**// Log.e(TAG, "I made it to getKeyAndStatus: onDataChange");**

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.child("History").getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot child : children){
                Log.d(TAG, "getKey: key = " + child.getKey());

                Ride ride = child.getValue(Ride.class);
                Log.e(TAG, "ride = " + ride);

                Log.d(TAG, "Driver = " + ride.getDriver());
                Log.d(TAG, "Rating = " + ride.getRating());
                Log.d(TAG, "Rider = " + ride.getRider());
                Log.d(TAG, "Price = " + ride.getRidePrice());
                Log.d(TAG, "status = " + ride.getStatus());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The above code only makes it as far as the Log "I made it to getKeyAndStatus: onDataChange"

**EDIT - Results**

[image: results]

Comment: is this userID?  `"-LGXaukR30LTjrL3ZNpt"`

Comment: -LGXaukR30LTjrL3ZNpt is the rideKey

Comment: `DatabaseReference keyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History").Child(rideKey);`

Comment: I tried getting the rideKey/requestId from the value event listener by creating another method and putting DatabaseReference keyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History"),child(rideKey) but comes out null.  I am assuming it is outside the scope?

Comment: Can I get the key first and then the value of the child "status"?

Comment: Im sorry, make what a double? rideKey?  Its a combo of letters and numbers.  I can get the key, but it gives me all the keys in the History node and I can't seem to get the value of "status'

Comment: @LizG Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51164518/1283715)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference historyRef = rootRef.child("History");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Ride ride = ds.getValue(Ride.class);

            Log.d(TAG, "Driver = " + ride.getDriver());
            Log.d(TAG, "Rating = " + ride.getRating());
            Log.d(TAG, "Rider = " + ride.getRider());
            Log.d(TAG, "Price = " + ride.getRidePrice());
            Log.d(TAG, "status = " + ride.getStatus());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
historyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be the values of your properties.

Note, when using the following line of code:

```
rideKey = String.valueOf(mDatabase.child("History").push().getKey());
```

You are generating another key instead of getting the existing one. Use the `push()` method only when you add objects not when you read them.

Comment: that's mean he still cannot access the rideKey?

Comment: @Zuhrain He is, by looping the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method.

Comment: @AlexMamo Perfection!

Comment: @AlexMamo How can I get the results so that it is showing the current History key because the print out is showing status = accepted before I submit a request.

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Don't add others questions/issues within the initial one, add a new one.

Comment: Ok sorry. I will do that

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference keyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History");
keyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        rideKey = String.valueOf(mDatabase.child("History").push().getKey());
        Log.d(TAG, "getKey: key = " + rideKey);

        DatabaseReference statusRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History").Child(rideKey).Child("status");
statusRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            History history = new History(); //If you make class for history
            history = dataSnapshot.getValue(History.class);
            textViewStatus.setText(history.getStatus());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I get the key but status = null

Comment: I added a History.java and I just get an error without any logs as to what the error is.  public class History {

    String status;

    public History() { }

    public History(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }    
}. It only does it when I add the above code that you edited as below:

Comment: History history = new History(); //If you make class for history
            history = dataSnapshot.getValue(History.class);
            textViewStatus.setText(history.getStatus());

Comment: It still comes out null

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference historyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("History");

    historyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "getKey: key = " + child.getKey());

                Ride ride = child.getValue(Ride.class);

                Log.d(TAG, "Driver = " + ride.getDriver());
                Log.d(TAG, "Rating = " + ride.getRating());
                Log.d(TAG, "Rider = " + ride.getRider());
                Log.d(TAG, "Price = " + ride.getRidePrice());
                Log.d(TAG, "status = " + ride.getStatus());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

//
//       "driver" : "ptnVOKounjXE9VrmZCCvKoZWluf1",
//               "rating" : 0,
//               "ridePrice" : 5.25,
//               "rider" : "C0RjB5NPZcTvWz9XiUAhpTDOK0C2",
//               "status" : "accepted",
//               "timestamp" : 1530662726

class Ride{
    // Remove @Exclude https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude
    private String driver;
    private int rating;
    private float ridePrice;
    private String rider;
    private String status;
    private long timestamp;

    public Ride() {
      // Empty Constructor  
    }
      // Getter & Setter 
  }
```

Comment: what is loge in private loge timestamp?

Comment: This line -  Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = mDatabase.child("History").getChildren(); - getChildren() doesn't work

Comment: @LizG Updated my answer  `loge` is to be `long`

Comment: @LizG **getChildren() doesn't work** please explain what happened update question with _Stacktrace_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174310/discussion-between-khaled-lela-and-lizg).

Comment: Check `dataSnapshot.child("History").getChildren()`

Comment: DatabaseReference keyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History");
        keyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

Comment: @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.child("History").getChildren();
                for (DataSnapshot child : children){
                    Log.d(TAG, "getKey: key = " + child.getKey());

Comment: Ride ride = child.getValue(Ride.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, "status = " + ride.getStatus());
                }
            }